# Youtube framerate low in full screen

Tags: 12.04, youtube, fullscreen, framerate

I've just installed Ubuntu 12.04 yesterday, and i'm having problems watching video's on YouTube. Once I get to full screen the frame rate drops to 16fps. 
My PC runs the latest games on very high, so I don't think my hardware would be a problem.

I'm using Chromium, but Firefox has the same issue.

Other flash based streaming videos work fine (like twitch.tv). It's the same low frame rate between HTML5 and Flash.

Basically it's a Youtube problem and not a flash issue.

Comment: have you installed the drivers for your graphic card?

Comment: Yes http://i.imgur.com/8Ij7FYV.png

Comment: Some more information: switching to HTML5 didn't help and other flash-based video players, such as twitch.tv, work fine.

Comment: okey, this is youtube only with flash/html5 having the same issue... cool

Comment: You may edit your question when you have more information or want to change it, rather than adding comments.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly Adobe Flash 11.2 has a blacklist of graphics cards which it will not allow to use hardware acceleration, even with a good card, so it's just luck if yours is supported and on the white list...

You could try installing MiniTube and gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg which allows you to search and play YouTube videos full screen using system codecs instead of the flash player...

Comment: You'll want to ensure the appropriate packages for hardware acceleration are installed as well, in my case I needed 'i965-va-driver' to enable Intel video acceleration. I'd add 'vainfo' as well so you can verify that acceleration is working.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps, but I'm not sure.

Switch to full screen and click the right mouse button and then click on Configurations and try to activate or deactivate graphic acceleration.

I once had problems with YouTube and this solved it.

Comment: Didn't help. I believe I read somewhere that that's not supported on Linux.

Comment: Personally, I don't think I've never gotten acceleration working in my life, not even on Windows. At least, I could never tell the difference (performance-wise) between acceleration being on or off.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it. It's because google chrome using 2 flash plugins.

> 1. Open up Google Chrome and in the address bar type chrome://plugins/
> 2. You will then see a Details link over to the right-hand side of the
>      page.  Click the + and you’ll see a long list of the installed plugins
>      in detail.
> 3. Look in the Flash section and find the line which has the
>      text ../pepflashplayer.so Click the Disable link next to this line and
>      restart the browser.

In last step I actually need only reload YouTube page :)

Full description: http://rextronics.co.uk/general/how-to-fix-jerky-full-screen-youtube-videos-in-google-chrome/

Comment: This is actually for Windows. You'll want to look for `/libpepflashplayer.so` in step 3 instead.

Comment: I even didn't spot .dll ending :) but I assume everybody can realise it..

Answer (score 0):

Try using SMPlayer with the SMTube, which will allow you to watch YouTube videos without using HTML5 or Flash (it uses MPlayer, which is much faster than Flash). You can try a number of output drivers, to see which one works best (xv works great for me).

To install SMPlayer, run the following

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rvm/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install smplayer smtube
```

Comment: Which repository is meant to be added by `add-apt-repository`? The name is probably missing in the snippet.

Comment: Oops! It's `rvm/ppa`. My bad, will edit.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem in Firefox by switching `layers.acceleration.disabled` to `false` and the `force` option to `true`.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)